# Краш бота на Heroku

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telebot, heroku, развертывание

Не могу понять в чем проблема.
Выполнил деплой бота на сервер Heroku.
Никаких ошибок не выдает, но после запуска бота и проверки, в консоли выдает:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Procfile:

```
worker: python main.py
```

requirements.txt:

```
pyTelegramBotAPI==3.8.2
```

Был бы рад любым советам

Comment: текстовую информацию лучше прилагать в виде текста: а) читать легче; б) можно копировать; в) поиск работает. исправить текст вопроса можно, нажав [edit] ниже текста вопроса

Answer (score 1):

[На хабре](https://qna.habr.com/q/606078) есть решение вашей проблемы, как минимум мне оно помогло в свое время